# Will changing Firebase validation rules affect existing data?

Tags: firebase

I'm making some changes to our existing Firebase rules and was wondering what will happen if some existing data wouldn't validate under the new rules. I'm assuming Firebase would just let the data be but wanted to be sure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is correct - changing validation rules won't have any impact on the current state of the data, and will only impact future writes.